# Is it bad if my program only achieves the results I want when compiler optimizations are turn off?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I have a larger project, I will not post the code here as it is too much for one post, written in c++. It is a checkers AI which uses Minimax and an evaluation function of my own design to find the best move for a checkers game. I have been struggling with unexpected results for about a month.

The problem is the implementation of minimax with alpha-beta pruning. I have both minimax and minimax with alpha-beta pruning implemented but the when I play the two AI against each other, the one without alpha-beta pruning wins consistently more often than the one with alpha-beta pruning. I recently realized that if I turn off compiler optimizations the two AI win relatively the same amount against each other.

Is it ok that the program only achieves the results I want when the optimizations are off or is this considered bad style?

My testing was playing matches of 500 games with one AI against the other where they alternate going first.

I can post code but it does not seem too applicable to this question.

EDIT:
I have seen a lot of comments about using valgrind and turning warnings on. I have done both of these but the problem in my code also never causes the program to crash and I am pretty sure my major memory leaks have been fixed. I can have the program run continuously for about a week without crashing (it did not crash after the week but ended naturally). The problem is never a runtime error it is that the program wins about 50% less often than it should.

```cpp
/**
 * Minimax with alpha-beta pruning. Alternate between the maximizing and
 * minimizing players move through a tree of nodes to return the most
 * favorable move to make assuming the opponent also makes the best moves.
 * Uses alpha-beta pruning to cut off subtrees which will not need to be
 * evaluated.
 * @param node the head of the tree
 * @param depth the depth in the tree to pursue
 * @param maximizingPlayer a boolean which should be true when called
 * @param alpha the alpha cut off value when called this should be
 *        -infinity
 * @param beta the alpha cut off value when called this should be
 *        +infinity
 * @return the value of the best node to choose which will be found in the
 *        successors of the head
 */
int AI::minimaxAB(Node *node, int depth, bool maximizingPlayer,
        int alpha, int beta) {
    int returnValue;
    if (depth == 0 || node->isTerminal()) {
        // we have reached our target depth or the end of the game 
        // so evaluate the board
        returnValue = evaluateBoardState(node->getBoardState());
        node->setValue(returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    auto *successors = node->getSuccessors();
    // each time minimax is recursively called it returns the node from the
    // params with the best value from its successors as its value
    if (maximizingPlayer) {
        // set value to something lower than is possible in the game
        returnValue = MIN;
        // set the curBest to something to be overwritten
        node->setValue(returnValue);
        for (auto &n : *successors) {
            returnValue = max(node->getValue(),
                    minimaxAB(n, depth - 1, false, alpha, beta));
            node->setValue(returnValue);
            alpha = max(alpha, returnValue);

            // if the alpha our current value is greater than the min break
            if (beta <= alpha)
                break; // causes worse moves to be chosen
        }
        return returnValue;

    } else { // minimizing player
        returnValue = MAX;
        // set the curBest to something to be overwritten
        node->setValue(returnValue);
        for (auto &n : *successors) {
            // Compare the new minimax node to the last one
            returnValue = min(node->getValue(),
                    minimaxAB(n, depth - 1, true, alpha, beta));
            node->setValue(returnValue);
            beta = min(beta, returnValue);

            // if the alpha our current value is greater than the min break
            if (beta <= alpha)
                break; // causes worse moves to be chosen
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

MIN and MAX are constant ints with values higher or lower than can be reached by the evaluation function. min and max functions return the highest of two integers.

Comment: *Is it bad if my program only achieves the results I want when compiler optimizations are turn off?* -- Yes.

Comment: Your program probably has one or more bugs that invoke undefined behavior.  Your best bet is to run the program that produces the wrong results and keep working with that version until the problem is fixed.  Don't use the "working" version as some sort of back-up plan, since you don't know when (or where) your program will fail to work, regardless of the optimizations.

Comment: No, it is not okay.    Programs that give different behaviours with different optimisation settings typically have some code - somewhere - that exhibits undefined behaviour.   The optimisation settings change the symptoms, but the cause is most likely in the code waiting to be found by end users after your code has passed testing.   Cases where the compiler is at fault do occur, but are much less likely than bugs in the program being compiled.

Comment: Run the program through some analysis tools like valgrind. They might spot the problem. Turn the compiler warnings way up and resolve all of them

Comment: Your code is certainly applicable, you have undefined behaviour and/or a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Is it bad? YES.

There are several reasons, to start you miss out of performance. Often one of the most compelling reasons to use C++. You can write abstractions that disappear because of optimization.

Though, more importantly, you are using undefined behavior. This means that your code will break when: you optimize, switch compiler, switch compiler version or even run it a second time.

As you haven't specified a compiler, Ill give a tip for Clang and Gcc: compile your program with [`-fsanitize=ubsan`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html). This instruments your exe and will tell you where you use UB that your compiler relies on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's bad. Your program obviously includes undefined behavior.

**Any undefined behavior in your program is a bug**. You don't want those bugs in your code. Eliminate them.

---

What to do?

Well, first of all, **ramp up the level of compiler warnings, and fix what the compiler complains about**. This is the easiest way to reduce undefined behavior in your program, and should catch most of the stuff that would be exploited by the optimizer.

Secondly, and equally important, **run your app with `valgrind`**. This will catch most of the memory related bugs.

Comment: It isn't obvious at all.  There are other possible explanations.

Comment: @BenVoigt Like which?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, the "time-limited search through potential future moves" which most modern game engines use for computer players.  If the time limit is kept the same, you expect an optimized build to evaluate a lot more positions and play better.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, of course. Excellent point :-) I just assumed that the behavior of the program was expected to be deterministic, so I ignored any time dependence. And even though it turned out my subconscious assumption was correct, it was nevertheless an assumption, and I thank you for pointing that out to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does your AI incorporate runtime measurements in any way?

For example, if you have a breadth-first search that continues exploring a game state tree until a time limit is reached.  Or if you seed a RNG more than once in the same program, using timestamps, then elapsed time will affect the RNG.

If your results depend on timing, then that will behave significantly different depending on optimization level, even in the absence of undefined behavior.  (Although reseeding an RNG during execution is a bug too).

I agree with others that your observed behavior is symptomatic of undefined behavior.  But other explanations do exist, and in AI those actually appear enough to be worth mentioning.

Comment: @mcnameel: You are limiting the search depth, not the search time.  Assuming that the search depth is a constant and doesn't adapt when the last turn took too long to run, then it's probably a bug not just timing-dependent results.  Have you checked whether, on the same problem input, the unoptimized and optimized search functions yield the exact same result?